# Eliminating equations in a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, block-matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have the following linear system:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Z}^{T} \\  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Y}^{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \gamma \mathbf{I} & -\mathbf{I}  \\ \mathbf{Z} & \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w} \\ b \\ \mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{\alpha} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix}$$

I want to eliminate the variables $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{e}$ from this equation. How can I do this?

The answer is apparently:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\mathbf{Y}^{T} \\ \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{Z} \mathbf{Z}^{T} + \frac{1}{\gamma} \mathbf{I} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} b \\ \mathbf{\alpha}  \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix} $$

I think there is a formula for 2x2 block matrix variable elimination...but I can't seem to find it anywhere...

Comment: I don't think it's correct. Write the matrix equation of rows 3 and 2.

Comment: @Andrei I fixed it using original notation. How about now?

Comment: This looks OK now

Comment: @Andrei Okay -- I managed to reduce it a bit, but can't figure out how actually eliminate the two variables I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Z}^{T} \\  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Y}^{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \gamma \mathbf{I} & -\mathbf{I}  \\ \mathbf{Z} & \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w} \\ b \\ \mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{\alpha} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix}$$

What you want is to keep the second row and eliminate $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ in the last row. To do that, multiply first row by $\mathbf{Z}$ and subtract it from the last row:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Z}^{T} \\  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Y}^{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \gamma \mathbf{I} & -\mathbf{I}  \\ \mathbf{Z-Z} & \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{ZZ}^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w} \\ b \\ \mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{\alpha} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix}$$
The next step is to multiply the third row by $1/\gamma$ and subtract it from the fourth row:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Z}^{T} \\  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Y}^{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \gamma \mathbf{I} & -\mathbf{I}  \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{I-I} & \mathbf{ZZ}^T+\frac1\gamma\mathbf{I} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w} \\ b \\ \mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{\alpha} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Z}^{T} \\  \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & -\mathbf{Y}^{T} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \gamma \mathbf{I} & -\mathbf{I}  \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{ZZ}^T+\frac1\gamma\mathbf{I} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{w} \\ b \\ \mathbf{e} \\ \mathbf{\alpha} \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix}$$
Now just take the 2nd and 4th rows, and ignore columns (and variables) where the entire column is $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: I see -- I got to that point but though I had to make the rows for $w$ and $e$ to be all zeros by row operations, which was getting me stuck.

Comment: No. The idea is that at the end the matrix looks diagonal. If a row is all 0, then that's a missing independent equation. For example, try to solve $x+y=1$ and $-x-y=-1$. If you write the matrix, you see that the determinant is 0. Same thing, if you have a row completely 0 in the matrix, the determinant is 0, so you need to get rid of it.

Comment: Sorry -- Im really out of practice with my elementary linear algebra!